# Sending customers to a PayPal payment page with a webhook? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, payment-processing, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm a bit confused with the PayPal (REST) integration.
What I want is the following:

- My customers on my website see a order-summary, they then click on
  'go to payment page'. I only need to set the Currency, Amount and Description.
- They arrive on a PayPal page where they choose to signin/as guest,    and choose creditcard/paypal account to pay, fill in all the data    etc.
- I get notified by using a webhook that they actually paid, and    process the payment internally.(Receiving an email about the status won't let me automate.)

Somehow all the examples I see are about sending complete payments through paypal, and not just 'setting up a payment page'. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps clarify:

There are 2 types of payments/funding :

- [`credit_card`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/)
- [`paypal`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/)

If by "payment page" you mean collecting payment info (credit card) on your website and sending it to a "gateway" for processing, then that's the `credit_card` flow option. There are account requirements for that (and PCI compliance).

The flow you describe above is the `paypal` flow. Your customers go to Paypal, select whatever payment instrument they have/choose (credit card, bank account, etc.) and then "approve" your *request* for a transaction.

When they "approve" - don't *confuse this with payment*, they are merely saying *"yes, I want to pay this merchant using my Paypal account/funds"*, they are redirected back to your web site/application (to complete/finish things). At which point you will perform the necessary steps to "complete" the transaction request (e.g. send an `execute`, `authorize`and `capture` request - depending on what you want).

So `excute` and `capture` (of an `authorization`) are the actual acts of "obtaining the actual payment so you get paid". You will get some *result* in the response to these requests at this stage for you to determine things.

If you've used the Classic API, this maps to `Express Checkout`. I'd map [`webhook`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/) to `IPN` (optional messaging/event tracking, and really isn't part of your payment/checkout flow).

Hth...

---

Update:

I'd really suggest that you take a look at the [SDK (.Net)](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK). It's very well maintained and Paypal dev support is awesome. The samples will really get you going quickly.

Comment: Thanks, gonna look into it:)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for that God forsaken link! I've been searching a whole week for a simple way to do things PayPal way and only now I've seen the light :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've taken a project which involves PayPal integration. It was a complete disaster for me. The struggle was tough on me for few days until I found the answer above AND after looking into the "Update" link, noticed they suggest to actually use a different NuGet.

So, this repository and quick start guideline was the cure to my pain with Paypal: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK